# create duplicate record in select query by every day with min and max time difference

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Recently I came across situation that I want to display one record in different dates if that record min and max dates are not in same date , up to now i have tried this two queries but one query is taking long time and another query not displaying all records. both queries are . 
Query 1(taking long time ):

```
select ((b.starttime+b.srlno) -1 ) datevals, to_char(((b.starttime+b.srlno) -1 ),'mm/dd/yyyy') dateval,
   extract(YEAR FROM (b.starttime+b.srlno)-1 ) eyear,
   extract(MONTH FROM (b.starttime+b.srlno)-1 )-1 emonth,
   extract(day from (b.starttime+b.srlno)-1 )-0 eday,
   b.* from  (select   ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (PARTITION BY
                                              a.id ORDER BY a.starttime NULLS LAST) SRLNO , 
          a.* from  (select  rr.id, rr.title ,min(rrd.starttime) starttime,
                     max(rrd.endtime) endtime,
                     to_char(min(rrd.starttime),'mm/dd/yyyy') startDate,
                     to_char(min(rrd.starttime),'fmHH:fmMI am') displaytime
                    -- JavaRoomBookingAPI.getCisnumber(rr.event_id) cisNumber
                   --  JavaRoomBookingAPI.getroomName(rr.id,rrd.room_id) roomName
              from roomreservation rr, roomreservationdetails  rrd,room r
              Where  rrd.roomreservation_id = rr.id 
                      and rrd.room_id= r.id and  rr.CANCELFLAG <> 1 
                      and  nvl(rrd.setuptime, rrd.starttime) != nvl(rrd.breakdowntime, rrd.endtime) 
                      and  rrd.starttime != rrd.endtime 
              group by    rr.id, rr.title
                        --JavaRoomBookingAPI.getCisnumber(rr.event_id)
                     --  JavaRoomBookingAPI.getroomName(rr.id,rrd.room_id)
              having   To_Date('11/01/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM') BETWEEN min(RRD.STARTTIME ) and max(RRD.Endtime) 
                       or 
                       To_Date('11/30/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM') BETWEEN min(RRD.STARTTIME )  and max(RRD.Endtime) 
                       or 
                       min(RRD.STARTTIME ) BETWEEN  To_Date('11/01/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM') and   To_Date('11/30/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM') 
                       or 
                       max(RRD.ENDTIME ) BETWEEN  To_Date('11/01/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM') and   To_Date('11/30/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM') 

            order by rr.id
            )a,
            (SELECT rownum repeat FROM dual
                   CONNECT BY LEVEL<= (select ceil(trunc(max(endtime))-trunc(min(starttime))) from roomreservationdetails)
            ) r
            where ceil(trunc(a.endtime)-trunc(a.starttime))+1 >= r.repeat 
            order by a.starttime,a.id) b order by datevals, b.title;
```

and 2 query is (not displaying all records):

```
select ((b.starttime+b.srlno) -1 ) datevals, to_char(((b.starttime+b.srlno) -1 ),'mm/dd/yyyy') dateval,
                   extract(YEAR FROM (b.starttime+b.srlno)-1 ) eyear,
                   extract(MONTH FROM (b.starttime+b.srlno)-1 )-1 emonth,
                   extract(day from (b.starttime+b.srlno)-1 )-0 eday,
                  b.* from  
                  (select   ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (PARTITION BY
                                                  a.id ORDER BY a.starttime NULLS LAST) SRLNO , a.* from 
                    (select  rr.id, rr.title ,min(rrd.starttime) starttime,
                    max(rrd.endtime) endtime,
                   to_char(min(rrd.starttime),'mm/dd/yyyy') startDate,
                   to_char(min(rrd.starttime),'fmHH:fmMI am') displaytime,
                   JavaRoomBookingAPI.getCisnumber(rr.event_id) cisNumber,
                   JavaRoomBookingAPI.getroomName(rr.id,rrd.room_id) roomName

         from roomreservation rr, roomreservationdetails  rrd,room r
         Where  rrd.roomreservation_id = rr.id 
                      and rrd.room_id= r.id and  rr.CANCELFLAG <> 1 and                
                   (
                   decode(to_char(rrd.starttime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 am',rrd.starttime + 1/1440,rrd.starttime) between 
                   (To_Date('11/01/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM')) And
                   (To_Date('11/30/2019 11:59 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM')) 
                         or 
                   decode(to_char(rrd.endtime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 pm',rrd.endtime - 1/1440,rrd.endtime) between 
                   (To_Date('11/01/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM')) And
                   (To_Date('11/30/2019 11:59 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM'))
                   or 
                   (To_Date('11/01/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM')) between 
                    decode(to_char(rrd.starttime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 pm',rrd.starttime + 1/1440,rrd.starttime) 
                     And
                    decode(to_char(rrd.endtime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 pm',rrd.endtime - 1/1440,rrd.endtime)
                   or 
                   (To_Date('11/30/2019 11:59 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM')) between 
                    decode(to_char(rrd.starttime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 pm',rrd.starttime + 1/1440,rrd.starttime) 
                     And
                    decode(to_char(rrd.endtime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 pm',rrd.endtime - 1/1440,rrd.endtime)
                  ) 
                 and  nvl(rrd.setuptime, rrd.starttime) != nvl(rrd.breakdowntime, rrd.endtime) 
                 and  rrd.starttime != rrd.endtime 
                 group by     rr.id, rr.title,JavaRoomBookingAPI.getCisnumber(rr.event_id),JavaRoomBookingAPI.getroomName(rr.id,rrd.room_id)
                 order by rr.id) a,
                               (SELECT rownum repeat FROM dual
                CONNECT BY LEVEL<= (select ceil(trunc(max(endtime))-trunc(min(starttime))) from roomreservationdetails
                                    where (decode(to_char(starttime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 am',starttime + 1/1440,starttime) between 
                                   (To_Date('11/01/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM')) And
                                   (To_Date('11/30/2019 11:59 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM')) or 

                                   decode(to_char(endtime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 pm',endtime - 1/1440,endtime) between 
                                   (To_Date('11/01/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM')) And
                                   (To_Date('11/30/2019 11:59 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM'))

                                   or 

                                   (To_Date('11/01/2019 12:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM')) between 
                                    decode(to_char(starttime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 pm',starttime + 1/1440,starttime) 
                                     And
                                    decode(to_char(endtime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 pm',endtime - 1/1440,endtime)

                                   or 

                                   (To_Date('11/30/2019 11:59 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi AM')) between 
                                    decode(to_char(starttime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 pm',starttime + 1/1440,starttime) 
                                     And
                                    decode(to_char(endtime,'hh:mi am'),'12:00 pm',endtime - 1/1440,endtime))
                )) r
                where ceil(trunc(a.endtime)-trunc(a.starttime))+1 >= r.repeat 
                order by a.starttime,a.id) b order by datevals, b.title;
```

Comment: Just a note on `extract(MONTH FROM (b.starttime+b.srlno)-1 )-1 emonth` - does it work for January?

Comment: Yes It is working fine , i'm using j query monthly calendar there I want to display months from 0 to 11.